# Algorithm to draw a perpendicular line on Google earth (KML)

Tags: kml, spherical-geometry, google-earth-pro, perpendicular

I have two points say A (lat,lon ) and B(lat,lon) and I want to draw a perpendicular bisector line to AB such that any point (C) on the perpendicular line satisfies AC=BC.

All I want is a function which takes A (lat,lon) B (lat,lon) and distance from the mid point of A and B and returns lat,lon (C) such AB = AC.

The end goal is to draw various circle with AB as chord.

Answer (score 3):

This is a part of the "median line" problem of maritime boundaries.  I
consider the solution of this problem using the azimuthal equidistant
projection in Section 14 of [Geodesics on an ellipsoid of
revolution](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1215).  Implementation of the general azimuthal equidistant
projection is given by [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sf.net) (for C++ and MATLAB).  There
are implementations of basic geodesic functions in various other
languages too (JavaScript, python, etc.); and implementing the azimuthal
equidistant projection is trivial once you have these.

All of this is for an ellipsoid, of course.  For a sphere, you can
presumably take some short cuts.  However, I would be inclined just to
implement the general ellipsoid solution and, if necessary, set the
flattening to zero to recover the spherical result.